# Value Animator android

Tags: android, animation

I am Trying to animate 3 images one after the other using value animator but i am not able to decide how to call the three handlers after regular intervals..Suppose there are 3 images and i m making three handlers for animating them.But i am able to bring the three images at a time but not one after the other at regular intervals.Please Help

This is my  UpdateListener which i am calling from my handler

```
public void startAnimation_image(final ImageView aniView) {

    animator = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(0, .8f);
    animator.setDuration(Constants.ANIM_DURATION);

    animator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {

        int Low = 10;
        int High = width-150;
        int R = (int) ((Math.random() * (High - Low)) + Low);

        @Override
        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
            float value = ((Float) (animation.getAnimatedValue())).floatValue();
            aniView.setTranslationX(R);

             Log.e("mscale",150*mScale +"");
             Log.e("value is", value+"");

            aniView.setTranslationY((mDisplaySize.bottom + (150*mScale))*value);

            x_point = aniView.getTranslationX();
            y_point = aniView.getTranslationY();
        }
    });

    animator.addListener(new AnimatorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animator arg0) {

        }
        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator arg0) {

        }
        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator arg0) {

            startAnimation();
        }
        @Override
        public void onAnimationCancel(Animator arg0) {

        }
    });

    animator.start();
}
```

This is one of my handler

```
@Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        super.handleMessage(msg);

        //int viewId = new Random().nextInt(STARS.length);

         id =   getApplicationContext().getResources().getIdentifier(STARS[0], "drawable", 
          getApplicationContext().getPackageName());

         inflate = LayoutInflater.from(StarsActivity2.this);


        img[0].setVisibility(ImageView.VISIBLE);
        img[0].setImageResource(id);

        mAllImageViews.add(img[0]);         

        LayoutParams animationLayout = (LayoutParams) img[0].getLayoutParams();
        img[0].setLayoutParams(animationLayout);
        Log.e("mHandler",img[0]+ "");
        startAnimation_image(img[0]);           
    }
};
```

There are similaarly three handlers and three update listeners.. Please help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can delay an animation by `offset` ms by calling

```
animation.setStartOffset(offset);
```

So for three images with duration `ANIM_DURATION`, you can use the following values to start them sequentially (probably by passing them as a parameter to `startAnimation_image()`)

```
// note: this is for illustrative purposes. You should put this in a loop
int firstOffset = 0 * ANIM_DURATION; // starts immediately
int secondOffset = 1 * ANIM_DURATION; // starts after the first animation is finished
int thirdOffset = 2 * ANIM_DURATION; // starts after the second animation is finished
// ... and so on.
```